# Linux bash script to tell me the type of a file

Tags: bash, file, types

I am writing a bash script and I want to check type of files.
Let's say I have a directory with different files. I want to check every file and see what type it is.

I need some command that will tell me: "OK, this file is a directory"
or "this file is pipe" or "this file is link", etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ls -la
```

tell you all about them, you just need to check the first char. e.g:

```
lrwxrwxrwx  1 kent kent  12 Apr  8 18:54 imlink -> /fpath/foo
-rw-r--r--  1 kent kent 242 Apr 10 16:40 file
drwxr-xr-x  2 kent kent  40 Apr 10 17:21 d/
```

in above example

```
l: link
-: file
d: dir
```

also you could write this awk line:

```
ls -la | awk '{t=(/^d/?"Directory":/^-/?"File":/^l/?"Link":"unknown");print $NF "---"  t}'
```

it would output something like:

```
d/---Directory
file---File
./.gitignore---Link
outputaa---File
```

Answer (score 4):

You can test files like so:

```
if [ -f $file ]
then
   echo "File is an ordinary file"
else
   echo "This is special file"
fi

if [ -d $file ]
then
   echo "File is a directory"
else
   echo "File is not a directory"
fi

if [ -s $file ]
then
   echo "File size is zero"
else
   echo "File size is not zero"
fi

if [ -e $file ]
then
   echo "File exists"
else
   echo "File does not exist"
fi

if [ -L $file ]
then
   echo "File is a link"
else
   echo "File is not a link"
fi
```

Have a look at more [file test operators](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/fto.html) (thanks birryree for the link)

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to check the [file](http://www.linuxcommand.org/man_pages/file1.html) command.